# React-native: facebook login release invalid hash key

Tags: facebook, react-native, react-native-fbsdk

I am using facebook login integration in my react-native app. Getting invalid hash key error with release key but debug key hash is working fine.

Environment :

```
"react": "16.0.0"
"react-native": "0.50.4"
"react-native-fbsdk": "^0.7.0"
```

Comment: What you did till now?

Answer (score 1):

You have to copy the Hash key of the error, than go to [facebook for developer page](https://developers.facebook.com/), select your app, than go to Settings > General and enter the Hask key on the Hash key section. If you test it your Android emulator run this command: `keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64`, copy the hash key and paste it also on your settings.

Comment: thanks @anonym , I have already try this. but after some days facing 
same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried add new key to FB app ? ( https://developers.facebook.com/apps/ )

Comment: yes i have already tried with the new key but getting the same issue, invalid key hash same issue , i am getting the hash key with the error is not the same key that i have put on Facebook app while facebook login.